# Pygame drawing on a surface vs drawing directly on display

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Which is the best way to draw objects in pygame?

1) Drawing on a surface and then flipping it into a display.

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((75, 25))
        self.surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
player = Player()
screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)
```

2) Directly drawing onto the display.

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x,y,width,height), thickness)
```

What's the difference between the two methods and which is preferred and why?

Also which one is faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to work with [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) then you should prefer to work with [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object, because you can add the object to a group.
When you use a group, then you can use the [`.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.update) to update all the Sprites in the Group and the [`draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) method to draw all the Sprites in the Group.

But note, the [`draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) method of `pygame.sprite.Group` uses the `.rect` and `.image` attribute of the object, thus you have to rename `.surf` to `.image`. For instance:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = pygame.Surface((75, 25))
        self.image.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_d]
            self.rect.x += 1
        # [...]
```

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

# [...]

my_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
my_group.add(Player(player_x, player_y))

while True:
    # [...]

    my_group.update()

    # [...]

    my_group.draw(screen)
```